# Why was a straightforward link in a comment misrendered in a notification email?

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks, email-notification

In [How can I do the work of Universal USB Installer from Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1796083/how-can-i-do-the-work-of-universal-usb-installer-from-linux?noredirect=1#comment2813584_1796083), I received the following email notification for the first comment, with a linked URL ending three characters too early:

[image: View of email with botched link]

The link displays correctly, and links correctly when I load the question, but clicking on the email took me to http://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/burn.h, which was a 404.

I believe this is a defect in URL recognition in email updates.

Comment: Looks like they trim the link after 70 characters, for unknown reason.